# Will CA's still validate internal IP's in SSL certs?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Just wondering what Certificate Authority (CA) policy is nowadays on validating someone's internal IP address in a certificate? I have heard that some CA's used to do this but won't anymore.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context to this? You typically get a certificate for a domain name or subdomain. Do you mean registering a certificate for a specific IP address? I've heard it's possible though I've never seen that in the wild. If that's what you mean then there is no way they could issue that since those IPs are often re-used.

Comment: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf (Peter Gutmann - Engineering Security) provides examples of certificates that were issued to internal IPs, see page 41, 73, or search for RFC 1918.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only will they not issue new certificates for unvalidatable IPs, but also revoke them in 2016.

https://www.digicert.com/internal-names.htm

> As from 1 October 2016, CAs shall revoke all unexpired Certificates.

More info in Mozilla's Wiki:  [CA:Problematic_Practices#Certificates_referencing_hostnames_or_private_IP_addresses](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:Problematic_Practices#Certificates_referencing_hostnames_or_private_IP_addresses)

Answer (score 2):

For public IP it must be checked that the IP is actually owned by the one who requests the certificate. Issuing certificates for private (reserved) IP is deprecated because obviously the ownership cannot be checked.

For more information see [CA baseline requirements](https://www.cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1.pdf) Sect 9.2.1.